# Codename One - span label did not show all content

Tags: codenameone

You can see the picture I attached, before the line "List of schools", it didn't show all of the contents on my `span-label`. 
Please help me to how to solve this problem.

[image]

Comment: Can you also post your hierarchy of Containers in the simulator click the Component Inspector and expand the area of the content pane. If you used the GUI builder a screenshot of the expanded tree would help in analyzing this

Answer (score 0):

Make sure one of your roots isn't a flow layout and that the UI is based on a scrollable box layout Y to give it the right size.